# How to obtain the individual density of $X$ when the joint distribution is given

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution

I have the following joint distribution of$X$ and $Y$,

$f(x,y)=\frac{\exp^{-y^2/2}}{y\sqrt(2\pi)}$

The support of the distribution is $0<|x|<y<\infty$. My question is how we will obtain the individual PDF of $X$. As far as the PDF of $Y$ is concerned, it can be obtained by simply integrating the joint density over $-y$ to $y$. beacuse we will consider the range of $x$ while calculating the PDF of $Y$. In the case of $x$, I am getting two different range of $y$. One is from, $x$ to $\infty$ and another is from $-x$ to $\infty$. How can we obtain, PDF of $X$ for such problem. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution for $x$ is no different than that for $y$: integrate.

Comment: I read your problem--please don't intimate that I did not.  Your problem recurs frequently in this forum--consider searching for it--and the answer is the most straightforward application of the definitions and techniques of integration, as I am trying to suggest.  If you would draw a picture of the support of this distribution, you would see that it is *not* in two parts: it is connected and, indeed, convex.

Comment: That's where I am getting confused in. I am getting a V-shaped region of integration. Now, if I have to obtain the density of $x$, then I have to integrate with respect to $y$. Right? Then, the range of Y is from $|x|$ to $\infty$. Am I right? I am really confused in this. Please guide me.

Comment: Draw the picture.  It shows a V shape extending from $y=0$ upwards, so the range of $y$ is $[0,\infty)$.  For each $y$ the values of $x$ within this region extend from $-y$ to $y$, so the range of $x$ is $[-y,y]$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much whuber. It was really a trivial doubt. But sometimes, it makes me really confused. Thank you once again.